# How to setup my mock Dao classes when using Guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, scalatest

A typical service looks like this:

```
trait BaseService extends LazyLogging {

  def getDb() = {
    DatabaseHelper.getDb       // database for the scala slick library
  }

}

abstract class UserService extends BaseService {
  def getById(userId: Int): Option[User]
}

class UserServiceImpl @Inject(val userDao: UserDao) extends UserService = {

  def getById(userId: Int): Option[User] = {
    getDb().withSession { implicit session =>
         return userDao.getById(userId)
    }
  }
}
```

Using Guice I wire up my objects like:

```
class ServiceModule extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
    bind[UserDao].to[UserDaoImpl]

    bind[UserService].to[UserServiceImpl]
  }
}
```

Now when I am unit testing using scalatest, **I am a bit confused how I can de-couple the database access since I want to mock the database responses**.

My spec looks like:

```
class UserServiceSpec extends UnitSpec with MockitoSugar {

val userService = injector.getInstance(classOf[UserService])


describe("UserServiceSpec") {
  it("should do someting") {
    val abc = userService.doSomething();
    abc.name should be("abc")
  }
}


}
```

My UnitSpec class wires up my Guice.

I am confused, where should I create the mock objects (using mockito) and how should I wire them using Guice?  In the ServiceModule or?

My design seems wrong since my BaseService has a connection to the database, I need to refactor that out somehow.

Looking for a way to get out of this bad design I currently seem to have, ideas?

Comment: I don't know guice+scala, but for Java, you would use Modules.override() to add a module that binds UserDao to a mock(UserDao) instance.

Comment: Can you avoid using Guice at all in your unit tests?  I'd do that.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Possible, didnt' think about that.  There is also an issue with my database pool being in the base service I need to factor out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the db connection to DAO layer. Your application should have three layers: controller -> service -> DAO. All the service layer needs to know is functionalities provided by DAO, i.e. CRUD operations; it should not know anything about db connection since that is DAO's responsibility.

I am not really sure about Slick framework, but for Play framework with Guice, it allows to disable "real" bindings (injected dependencies) that you expect when the application is running and enable bindings that are only for testing like this:

```
implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .configure(appConfig)
  .disable(classOf[ReactiveMongoModule], classOf[CommonModule])
  .bindings(bind(classOf[ReactiveMongoApi]).toInstance(api))
  .bindings(TestDaoModule())
  .build()
```

This is a complete integration test (controller layer), hope that it helps: https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/test/controllers/UserControllerTest.scala